# Xamarin forms stroke line between cell values?

Tags: xamarin.forms, devexpress

Devexpress grid allows templates, and I have got what I need, but I want the line as shown in the drawing. Is that possible? What I am talking about is the stroke line sep weight and the reps values? I would also love if I could have the sep column headings inside weight | rep as in drawing?

https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/400543/xamarin-forms/data-grid/index

```
<dxg:TemplateColumn FieldName="PU" Caption="Pull Up" 
   IsReadOnly="true" AllowSort="False" MinWidth="200">

    <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="15, 0, 0, 0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Item.Type,
                StringFormat ='Pull
                 Up Type: {0}'}" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
                <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Item.PU, 
                StringFormat ='Weight: 
                {0}'}" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
                <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding 
                Item.PUReps, StringFormat = 
               'Reps: {0}'}" Grid.Row="1"></Label>  
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
</dxg:TemplateColumn>
```

What it should look like.

[image]

Comment: I doubt there is any simple way to do it.  The easiest might be to create a dynamic image that contains the values, or maybe a grid with two labels for the values that is overlaid with an image for the divider

Comment: Two details that might help. 1) I see this grid control has [DataGridView.ColumnHeaderContentTemplate Property](https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/DevExpress.XamarinForms.DataGrid.DataGridView.ColumnHeaderContentTemplate). 2) I don't see a template for a cell. CellStyle seems limited. But if you find some way around that, a diagonal line can be drawn using [Xamarin.Forms Shapes: Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used **Xamarin.Forms Shapes: Line** to achieve this effect.
Here is the xaml code：

```
<StackLayout>
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" RowSpacing="0" x:Name="mygrid" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        <BoxView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"  BackgroundColor="Black" WidthRequest="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
        <BoxView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"  BackgroundColor="Black" WidthRequest="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
        <BoxView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"  BackgroundColor="Black" WidthRequest="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the cs code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        int a = mygrid.RowDefinitions.Count;
        int b = mygrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= b; j++)
            { 
                mygrid.Children.Add(new Line
                {
                    X1 = 0,
                    Y1 = 50,
                    X2 = 125,
                    Y2 = 0,
                    Stroke = Brush.Black
                }, j-1, i-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope it will work with devexpress though any idea how one would angle the text on the top and bottom to match?

Comment: I think you only need to set the HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions in the grid to start or end.